deno fetch post not working ... as expected
I have some simple fetch code which is working in node but not in deno and I've search all the possible tickets and docs and I'm still at a loss:
// some code to get the `from` parameter 
// ...
const fd=new URLSearchParams()
Object.entries({
    username: "myuser@my.email",
    password: "mypassword",
    submit: "Login",
    from: "L21lbnUv",remote:"",action:"auth"
}).forEach(([k,v])=>{fd.set(k,v)})
const r = await fetch(`https://freedns.afraid.org/zc.php?step=2`,{redirect:"manual",method:"POST",body:fd});


What I'm expecting is a 302 response and 3 set-cookie headers
... and that is what I'm getting from node;
but from deno I get a 302 response with the same url as location header and one cookie (so no login)
I understand that this is tightly linked to the site's backend, but this works fine in both curl and node.
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Don't you need to call to toString() on fd before using it as a fetch body?

@mfulton26, not according to the docs(https://deno.land/api@v1.42.1?s=BodyInit)

There's not really anything actionable here without seeing the code controlling the server responses in a [mre].
